# Passing model to filter

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-routing

How do I actually pass model to a filter?

I have a form that allows user with enough privilege to edit and save a book.

```
Route::model('book', 'Book');
Route::get('/edit/{book}', array('before' => 'my_filter', 'uses' => 'BookController@showForm'));

Route::filter('my_filter', function() {
    // check if authenticated has enough privilege to edit a book
    // Would like to do something like $book->AuthorID == Auth()::user()->AuthorID
});
```

Any suggestion? Thanks!

Comment: Just figured a solution. In `my_filter`, adding `$book = $route->getParameter('book')` can retrieve `Book` model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Route::filter('my_filter', function($route) {
  $book = $route->getParameter('book');
  if( $book->AuthorID == Auth()::user()->AuthorID){
    // .......
  }
});
```